# PHP extract url from HTML using DOMDocument and/or Regex

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I'm trying to get the value for the key `poster` in the html, which is `https:\/\/example.com\/avt\/test.jpg`

html

```
    <html><body> 
    <script>
         (function(window, sabaPlayer) {
          var options = JSON.parse('{"poster":"https:\/\/example.com\/avt\/test.jpg"}')
 })
    </script>
    </body></html>
```

Can i do this with DOMXPath?  The page has way more html but this is the specifc part i want.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$result = $xpath->query("//script");

foreach($result as $node) {


}
```

How do i do this?

The result i want is the string `https:\/\/example.com\/avt\/test.jpg`

Comment: What's wrong with what you have there? Seems like a good start...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `regex` to fetch this value which will be easier.

```
$txt = <<<TXT
<html><body> 
  <script>
     (function(window, sabaPlayer) {
      var options = JSON.parse('{"poster":"https:\/\/example.com\/avt\/test.jpg"}')
     })
</script>
</body></html>
TXT;

$matches = [];
preg_match('/JSON.parse\(\'(.*)\'\)/iu', $txt, $matches);

$parsed = json_decode($matches[1]);
```

Output will be an `stdClass` with property `poster`

```
stdClass Object
(
    [poster] => https://example.com/avt/test.jpg
)
```

Here is how to access the URL `$parsed->poster`